# How to redirect all urls containing a ? querystring

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got a script, that I am not able to edit, that generates a querystring, like:

```
www.example.com/?target=xyz
```

I need to redirect all links on the website containing a `?target` querystring to `www.example.com/targets/?target=xyz`.

I thought that it could be a best practice (except changing the script) to create a `mod rewrite` solution, but I am not able to do it. Would you suggest another solution than solving this using a `htaccess`, or if not how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)target= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /targets/ [R=301,L]
```

best practice: changing the script... Normally this is a configuration parameter at the beginning